# How to access rows in table generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've generated a table in my html by using this code:

```
 var board=document.getElementById("tab");

    for(var i=0; i<lvl1.rows; i++ )
    {

            var row=board.insertRow();

            for(var j=0; j<lvl1.cols; j++)
            {
                var cell = row.insertCell();       
            }       
    }
```

The point  is to keep the design of the page almost totally separated from the game engine (creating a Minesweeper game).
Imagine I want to change the colour of the cell in position [2][3]. How can I change the background colour of this cell if I don't have the "td's" and "tr's" in the HTML code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To access the `i`th cell of row `j`, use:

```
board.rows[j].cells[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color style of a cell like this.

```
board.rows[j].cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```